# maxTaskExecutePerRun by a NonStickyEventExecutorGroup

Tags: netty

> public NonStickyEventExecutorGroup(EventExecutorGroup group,
>                                      int maxTaskExecutePerRun)
>
> Creates a new instance. Be aware that the given EventExecutorGroup MUST NOT contain any OrderedEventExecutors.

The documentation does not say much about the maxTaskExecutePerRun. 
My understanding: it put a cap on the number of runnable executed by the eventExuctor. 
What would happen if the submitted task exceeds the max?

I run some tests but I did not see any difference.

Answer (score 1):

It basically specify the number of tasks to process while on the `Thread` before give up and let another `Thread` takeover the processing of the tasks in the `Queue`.

So with this in mind have some "limit" here will allow to return a `Thread` to a pool and make it useable for other things.